# JHipster error when running

Tags: java, bower, jhipster

I am trying to get started with JHipster, but keep running into issues.

The latest issue is, after going through the JHipster cli prompt, and answering a series of questions, then it proceeds to download the internet, until it hits the following error:

```
swagger-ui#2.1.3 src/main/webapp/bower_components/swagger-ui

angular-i18n#1.4.8 src/main/webapp/bower_components/angular-i18n

angular-ui-router#0.2.15 src/main/webapp/bower_components/angular-ui-router
└── angular#1.4.8
events.js:141
      throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event
      ^

Error: spawn grunt ENOENT
    at exports._errnoException (util.js:856:11)
    at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:178:32)
    at onErrorNT (internal/child_process.js:344:16)
    at nextTickCallbackWith2Args (node.js:474:9)
    at process._tickCallback (node.js:388:17)
anton@anton-K93SV:~/git/jhipster-qs$
```

What should I do now?

Comment: Try running `npm install` again, you probably just had a network error when downloading the packages

Comment: I tried that, but unfortunately it did not help. Still get the same error.

Comment: did you delete the node_modules folder before running it again? if not try that as well, it has helped me few times

Comment: I have uninstalled and reinstall node. Still getting the same error.

Answer (score 1):

This error is obtained if you don't have gulp installed. Run:

```
npm install -g gulp
```

Answer (score 0):

Run

```
sudo npm install -g grunt-cli
```

This is the step #7 of this tutorial:
http://jhipster.github.io/installation/